# Why comparing is working this way?

Tags: java

I have wrote my custom comparator:

```
     public static Comparator<String> compareEThenEverything(){
            return (s1, s2) -> {
                if(s1.toLowerCase().startsWith("e") && s2.toLowerCase().startsWith("e")) 
                return 0;
                if(s1.toLowerCase().startsWith("e")) return 1;
                return -1;
            };
        }
```

And I want to sort my array that all strings that starts with 'e' will be first.

By why the current comparator is working reversed ? It seems like that the word with "e" at first character is greater than word with other char, because I returning 1 - not -1?

Why is this happens ?

Comment: Reading the first line of Comprator javadoc should be enough: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-

Comment: Do you know that your second condition is never evaluated since its first part is identical to the previous if statement?

Comment: @NoMercy ye, you are right

Comment: Pay close attention to the formal requirements of the `compare` method: e.g. "The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.". You violate this, e.g. for inputs `"a"` and `"b"` (or `""` and `""`, for that matter).

Answer (score 4):

`1` means that the **first** argument is **greater** than the **second** argument and since the default order is increasing then yes anything starting with *e* will come last, so what you need is to swap `-1`, `1`:

```
public static Comparator<String> compareEThenEverything(){
    return (s1, s2) -> {
        if(s1.toLowerCase().startsWith("e"))
            return -1;
        if(s1.toLowerCase().startsWith("e") && s2.toLowerCase().startsWith("e"))
            return 0;
        return 1;
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, although instead of `return 0` you should be `return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2)` since the name is "compare E then everything"... kind of implies they need to compare everything at some point. =)

Comment: This   `if(s1.toLowerCase().startsWith("e")) return -1;`
doesn't respect the symmetric principle.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you see it "reversed" because [Comparator contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) works the opposite way:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a **negative integer**, zero, or a positive integer as **the first argument is less than**, equal to, or greater than the second.

I highly recommend you to read [Comparator javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) before going forward.

---

This comparator will make strings that start with 'e' always appear first.

```
private static final Comparator<String> E_FIRST = (s1, s2) -> {
    char s1c = s1.isEmpty() ? (char) Character.UNASSIGNED : Character.toLowerCase(s1.charAt(0));
    char s2c = s2.isEmpty() ? (char) Character.UNASSIGNED : Character.toLowerCase(s2.charAt(0));
    return s1c == 'e' ? (s1c == s2c ? 0 : -1) : s2c == 'e' ? 1 : 0;
};
```

Also, this implementation only checks the first character instead of converting the whole string into lowercase.

If you want other strings to be sorted as well, you can chain it with `String. CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`:

```
E_FIRST.thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```